# Oracle imp utility with unicode characters

Tags: oracle, unicode, import

I am currently trying to import a .dat file using the Oracle imp utility, I am having issues with the unicode characters.

The file loads fine for the rest of the data, I have tried Setting the NLS_LANG parameter to AL32UTF8 and also tried several other charactersets.

The data was unloaded in the US in a system with US7ASCII encoding, we have a UK AL32UTF8 database, is this going to cause an issue?

I cant find anything in the oracle docs that might help. Any information anyone could give would be a great help.

Comment: What is the source database character set?  What was the `NLS_LANG` on the client where the export was generated?  I believe you are saying that one of these is `US7ASCII` but I'm not sure which of the two you are saying is using 7-bit ASCII.  When you say that you "have a UK AL32UTF8 database" I assume that means that the target database has a character set of AL32UTF8.

Comment: yes you are correct, the target database has AL32UTF8 and the NLS_LANG on the client where the export was generated was AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII. Thanks